# jquery dropdownlist, onchange reload page using Get request with ID of dropdown value

Tags: javascript, jquery

When someone selects an item in a dropdown, I want to reload the current page with the value of the ID in the selected item in the querystring like:

```
http://www.example.com/mypage?id=234
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Could you provide an example of the dropdown list as well?

Answer (score 25):

You can use the raw javascript version that Dutchie432 noted or the jQuery version.

```
<select id="the_select">
  <option value="123">Go to 123</option>
  <option value="456">Go to 456</option>
<select>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $("#the_select").change(function(){
    window.location='http://www.domain.com/mypage?id=' + this.value
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 14):

jQuery is not needed. basic Javascript will do you just fine in this case.

Just add an "onchange" event to your drop-down

```
<select onchange="doAction(this.value);">
  <option value="123">Go to 123</option>
  <option value="456">Go to 456</option>
<select>
```

then, add the function that gets called when the value changes

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
    function doAction(val){
        //Forward browser to new url
        window.location='http://www.domain.com/mypage?id=' + val;
    }
--></script>
```

**OR The compact version, without seperate JS Code**

```
<select onchange="window.location='http://www.domain.com/mypage?id=' + this.value;">
  <option value="123">Go to 123</option>
  <option value="456">Go to 456</option>
<select>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
<select id="items" onselect="javascript:reloadPage(this)">
  <option name="item1">Item 1</option>
</select>
```

script:

```
function reloadPage(id) {
   document.location.href = location.href + '?id=' + id.value;
}
```

Comment: What about second get request; wont it append query string to current url which already have query string.

Comment: jsut a one time solution. comment above asks the same question as mine..

Answer (score 1):

Following code will Validate

- Is URL is having respective parameter if not that add it.
- If parameter is found that replace the parameter with the new
  selected value.
- Reload the page.

  ```
  $(function () {
      $("#the_select").change(function () {

          if (window.location.href.indexOf("?") < 0) {
              window.location.href = window.location.href + "?mypage="+ this.value;
          }
          else{
              window.location.href = replaceUrlParam(window.location.href, "mypage", this.value)
          } 

      });
  });


  function replaceUrlParam(url, paramName, paramValue)
  {
      var pattern = new RegExp('\\b(' + paramName + '=).*?(&|$)')
      if (url.search(pattern) >= 0)
      {
          return url.replace(pattern, '$1' + paramValue + '$2');
      }
      return url + (url.indexOf('?') > 0 ? '&' : '?') + paramName + '=' + paramValue
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Better is to use `<form>` because, in another way, the all fields not append in url. In this cause `@BJ Patel` wanted resolve this problem in the another answer in here.
So, If you use `form` for this, anytime you will have another fields in form, after submit that all append and replace with new value, in URL. See:

```
<form method="get" action="http://www.example.com/mypage" id="form">
  <select id="the_select" name="id">
    <option value="123">Go to 123</option>
    <option value="456">Go to 456</option>
    <option value="789">Go to 789</option>
  <select>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $("#the_select").change(function(){
    $("#form").submit();
  });
});
</script>
```